# R: ordering and arrange data by first column

Tags: r, excel, sorting

I have my data  in this form:

```
tot          zona a         zonab            zona c
anna        francesco     anna           barbara 
antonio     giancarlo   antonio     elena 
barbara     giuseppe    barbara     francesco 
elena       roberto     giuseppe    giancarlo 
francesco   silvia          roberto     gianluca 
giancarlo   sussanna    silvia           giovanna 
gianluca    valentina   valentina   giuseppe
giovanna            roberto 
giuseppe            silvia 
roberto             
silvia          
sussanna            
valentina
```

What I want to do is order them according to the first column  such as the output will be something like this (where every column is order according to tot, and there is a blank space for the missing value - NA will be fine as well):

```
tot        zona a           zonab          zona c
anna     anna           barbara 
antonio                 antonio     
barbara                 barbara 
elena                          elena
francesco   francesco              francesco
giancarlo   giancarlo              giancarlo 
gianluca                    gianluca 
giovanna             giovanna 
giuseppe    giuseppe    giuseppe
roberto     roberto     roberto     roberto 
silvia   silvia             silvia          silvia 
sussanna    sussanna    valentina   
valentina   valentina
```

I have tried this in R:

```
newdat <- spe[order(row.names(spe)),]
```

or

```
Spe <- arrange(SPE, Total)
```

or

```
SPE_NEW <- data[order(spe$row.names),]
```

This is only a subset I have tons of data, is there a way to sort my data? Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are starting with something that looks like this:

```
mydf
#          tot     zonaa     zonab     zonac
# 1       anna francesco      anna   barbara
# 2    antonio giancarlo   antonio     elena
# 3    barbara  giuseppe   barbara francesco
# 4      elena   roberto  giuseppe giancarlo
# 5  francesco    silvia   roberto  gianluca
# 6  giancarlo  sussanna    silvia  giovanna
# 7   gianluca valentina valentina  giuseppe
# 8   giovanna   roberto                    
# 9   giuseppe    silvia                    
# 10   roberto                              
# 11    silvia                              
# 12  sussanna                              
# 13 valentina
```

You can try using `match`:

```
within(mydf, {
  zonaa <- zonaa[match(tot, zonaa)]
  zonab <- zonab[match(tot, zonab)]
  zonac <- zonac[match(tot, zonac)]
})
#          tot     zonaa     zonab     zonac
# 1       anna      <NA>      anna      <NA>
# 2    antonio      <NA>   antonio      <NA>
# 3    barbara      <NA>   barbara   barbara
# 4      elena      <NA>      <NA>     elena
# 5  francesco francesco      <NA> francesco
# 6  giancarlo giancarlo      <NA> giancarlo
# 7   gianluca      <NA>      <NA>  gianluca
# 8   giovanna      <NA>      <NA>  giovanna
# 9   giuseppe  giuseppe  giuseppe  giuseppe
# 10   roberto   roberto   roberto      <NA>
# 11    silvia    silvia    silvia      <NA>
# 12  sussanna  sussanna      <NA>      <NA>
# 13 valentina valentina valentina      <NA>
```

Here's the same idea, implemented more succinctly.

```
mydf2 <- mydf ## Work on a copy instead of overwriting your data
mydf2[-1] <- lapply(mydf2[-1], function(x) x[match(mydf2[[1]], x)])
mydf2
```

---

Here's some data in a reproducible format:

```
mydf <- structure(list(tot = c("anna", "antonio", "barbara", "elena", 
    "francesco", "giancarlo", "gianluca", "giovanna", "giuseppe", 
    "roberto", "silvia", "sussanna", "valentina"), zonaa = c("francesco", 
    "giancarlo", "giuseppe", "roberto", "silvia", "sussanna", "valentina", 
    "roberto", "silvia", "", "", "", ""), zonab = c("anna", "antonio", 
    "barbara", "giuseppe", "roberto", "silvia", "valentina", "", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), zonac = c("barbara", "elena", "francesco", 
    "giancarlo", "gianluca", "giovanna", "giuseppe", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "")), .Names = c("tot", "zonaa", "zonab", "zonac"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Hello Ananda. Can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579956/excel-2007-fill-certain-blanks-in-column-a-with-data-from-column-b-while-retai

Comment: @Boris_yo, sorry, not actually an Excel user!